# PHP CURL doesn't finish request

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https, php-curl

I'm using curl library on PHP7.2 for to send request on website.
this is the link:

https://pje.trt15.jus.br/pje-consulta-api/api/processos/dadosbasicos/00114894220185150137

If send the request using the cURL on terminal, I get theses headers and response:

```
curl https://pje.trt15.jus.br/pje-consulta-api/api/processos/dadosbasicos/00114894220185150137 -H "x-grau-instancia: 2" -v

*   Trying 23.46.150.41...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to pje.trt15.jus.br (23.46.150.41) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.trt15.jus.br
*  start date: Sep 28 17:24:47 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 27 17:24:46 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "pje.trt15.jus.br" matched cert's "pje.trt15.jus.br"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55c5a2365600)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):

\> GET /pje-consulta-api/api/processos/dadosbasicos/00114894220185150137 HTTP/2
> Host: pje.trt15.jus.br
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> x-grau-instancia: 2
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/2 200
< x-request-id: c85077d1-ce68-4ce5-8e88-744203769ea7
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 150
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
< feature-policy: camera 'none'; microphone 'none'
< expires: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 17:10:48 GMT
< cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< pragma: no-cache
< date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 17:10:48 GMT
< server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
< server-timing: edge; dur=115
< server-timing: origin; dur=10
<
* Connection #0 to host pje.trt15.jus.br left intact
```

But, if I use the php library, the header is other, and the request don't finish

```
*   Trying 23.46.150.41...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to pje.trt15.jus.br (23.46.150.41) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: DEFAULT:!DH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.trt15.jus.br
*  start date: Sep 28 17:24:47 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 27 17:24:46 2021 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.

\> GET /pje-consulta-api/api/processos/dadosbasicos/00114894220185150137 HTTP/1.1
Host: pje.trt15.jus.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-type: application/json
x-grau-instancia: 2
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://pje.trt15.jus.br/pje-consulta-api/api/processos/dadosbasicos/00114894220185150137');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,['x-grau-instancia: 1']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DEFAULT:!DH');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$ping = curl_exec($ch);
```

Why the curl library don't continue with HTTP2 request? Why the hedaers is different?

Comment: Could be a too old curl library. Try upgrading PHP.

Comment: this is not a option for me, I use pthreads in prod env and only works with php 7.2  :´(.

Comment: the curl library wouldn't be the same that curl installed in SO?

Comment: What do you mean PHP library? why not use curl on PHP? or use : curl to php https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ paste your curl and copy the code to your code echo the result... did you try that?

Comment: I should have written extension instead of library. I was using 7.1 having a header bug with curl and it was solved by upgrading to 7.3 back then. This is just a suggestion. Maybe it helps using Guzzle instead?

Comment: I updated the question with my code. I already test in another envoriment with PHP7.4 and all works fine, but in prod env I dont upgrade php because I use pthreads

Comment: Alternative suggestion to Guzzle: Use curl via command line. Or another hacky idea: copy the working php7.4 extension over the older.

Comment: Yet another idea, use Docker.

Comment: ```if (false === $ping) {
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
}```
returns 

> SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the server uses TSL1.3 you may try specifing a value with `curl_setopt` for `CURLOPT_TLS13_CIPHERS`

From the [**manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> The list of cipher suites to use for the TLS 1.3 connection. The list must be syntactically correct, it consists of one or more cipher suite strings separated by colons. This option is currently used only when curl is built to use OpenSSL 1.1.1 or later. If you are using a different SSL backend you can try setting TLS 1.3 cipher suites by using the CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST option.

Note that there a three requirements:

> Available since PHP 7.3.0

> libcurl >= cURL 7.61.0.

> Available when built with OpenSSL >= 1.1.1.